# SQL Server 2012 Mirrored database in suspect status

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have a SQL Server 2012 database that is being mirrored that has become suspect due to the log drive on the primary becoming full. We have broken the mirror from the secondary and the database on the primary is in a recovery status but when trying to bring it online to repair the primary the database it gives an error that it is part of a mirror. How can we clear the mirror flag and repair the database on the primary?

Comment: What all have you tried so far? Whats the exact error you get?

Comment: On the secondary ran alter database set partner off to break the mirror. Database on the primary is now in a "In Recovery" status, when trying to recover the database get an error that the database is part of a mirroring solution